# Table-like floated div with height 100%

Tags: css

Here are two examples.

One with required result, using tables:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dhn3B/

Another with divs:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rpmnq/1/

How to make example with divs be the same as example with tables?

I'm not good at divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to [add `overflow: hidden`](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats) to the "text" `div`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Rpmnq/5/

This will work in IE7+ and all modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css `display:table-cell` property like this:

```
.wr div{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/Rpmnq/4/

Comment: It's not supported in IE7, can forget about IE6, but IE7 should be yet supported.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a float on both divs and clear the float right after:

```
<div class="wr">
    <div class="float" style="width:100px">image here</div>
    <div class="float" style="width:280px">some text here some more some more some more
some more some more some more some more some more some more some more some more some 
more some more some more some more some more some more some more some more some 
more some more</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle it](http://jsfiddle.net/Rpmnq/6/)

Comment: Oh, so the right div with text should have fixed width and if width is greater than parent width minus first child width, then it gets under it. But 400-75=325 , but when i set width to 320 it's dropped to second line http://jsfiddle.net/Rpmnq/7/ . Without margin and fixed 75 width it's all right http://jsfiddle.net/Rpmnq/8/ why it that happening with margin?

Comment: @Beck because the margin is added to the width, and when its greater than the parrent element (400px) it wraps around the next line: 65 +325 + 20 (margin left and margin right) = 410px

Comment: Yea i got it, just forgot the second block have same class as first one. So it's 2x10px.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a box and put the text in it like this:

```
   #box{
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
    }
```

and call the div as:
        
    text text text

Is that what you would like?

Comment: Could you please update jsfiddle example? Height should not be fixed in my case.

Comment: I am on my phone right now, ao I may not be able to use jsfiddle, but I updated my code by removing the height. It will scale with the text

Answer (score 0):

A couple other samples:

http://jsfiddle.net/basilkot/uKewV/

http://jsfiddle.net/basilkot/4aEbe/

Comment: Not a solution for me, that's why: http://jsfiddle.net/uKewV/1/ , then parent should have mix-height, which is not supported by old IE.

Comment: Second example works. Interesting :) , but what margin-right:-400px; is for, it works without it pretty well: http://jsfiddle.net/4aEbe/1/ anyway thanks for second solution.